# Copy binary image data into a string

Tags: c++, image, wininet

I need to send image data over network using HttpSendRequest POST request.
For this purpose I am creating a string , adding some parameters to string, then I need to add raw image data.

Now I would like to know how can I send the image in post request.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the image data to the `lpOptional` parameter.

If by chance you're trying to mimic the user pressing the submit button, you'll first have to format the body of the HTTP request to conform to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or in this case `multipart/form-data` content type.

Comment: actually I need to add some string params before image raw data like 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=XXX
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

So I need to construct a buffer with these strings and then append image raw data

Comment: @Alien01, You shouldn't send `Content-Disposition` header in a HTTP request. I don't fully understand what you're trying to do. Perhaps you could edit the question and clarify?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to pass the data into a string and decode it on the server side, look into applying a [base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) on it before sending and base64 decoding upon receiving.